# mysqli_fetch_assoc() is not getting any data/fetching empty data

Tags: php

So, I am making an Admin panel for my webpage, but I have run into a bug/mistake. When I want to fetch data from Database, using uid as a reference, i don`t get any data. Here is my code:

```
 <?php

  session_start();

  $secretToken = "UWAL2019";

  include '../inc/db.inc.php'; # Including Database Info

  if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # If access has been sent straight trough using link, not submit button

    header("Location: index.php"); # Sending client back to Login page
    exit(); # (for security purpouses) Exiting this page
  }else {
    # If access has been sent using button

    $uid = $_POST['uid']; # Getting subbmitted Username, using POST method
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd']; # Getting subbmitted Password, using POST method

    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) { # If some fields are empty

      header("Location: index.php?status=empty"); # Sending client back to Login page, with status EMPTY
      exit();

    }else { # If all fields are full
      # Login credentials checking, using Database

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE uid='$uid';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck > 0) {

       header("Location: index.php?status=wrongCK");
       exit();
     }else {

       if ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         if ($data['pwd'] != $pwd) {

           header("Location: index.php?status=wrongRS");
           exit();
         }else {

           $_SESSION['secretToken'] = $data['secretToken'];

           if ($_SESSION['secretToken'] != $secretToken) {

             session_destroy();
             header("Location: index.php?status=wrong_token");
             exit();

           }else {

             $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
             $_SESSION['uid'] = $data['uid'];
             $_SESSION['pwd'] = $data['pwd'];
             $_SESSION['maskName'] = $data['maskName'];
             $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];

             header("Location: adminPanel.php");
             exit();
           }
         }
       }else {
         header("Location: index.php?status=fetch_error");
         exit();
       }
     }
    }
  }

 ?>
```

FYI: "?status" varibles in the header is error code. My code stops at ?status=fetch_error and I cant get past it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Stop redirecting all the time, and instead make a bit of sensible debug outputs - check function return values, ask the database what error might have occurred, etc.

Comment: Man this code is a mess lool.. try and use functions it will make your code more linear, easier to understand and modify. Also you need to escape your inputs or your liable to having your database deleted!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    header("Location: index.php?status=wrongCK");
    exit();
}
```

You are basically saying "If user was found, redirect".  I think you should have:

```
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    header("Location: index.php?status=wrongCK");
    exit();
}
```

which will redirect when a user is NOT found.